# How to get Current Page URL in MediaWiki

Tags: php, mediawiki

I am trying to get the current page's url and store it to a variable in my custom skin template. I am trying to do this so I can use this url for other purposes. I am trying to do something like this

```
function currentpageurl() //Some Custom function
{
    $url= [something that can get current page's url in mediawiki and store it to this variable]
    .....use the $url variable for other purposes....
    ......
    .....
}
```

Does Mediawiki has a way that can identify the current page's url or is my only option to find the current page is by using this method?

```
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're writing a [QuickTemplate](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classQuickTemplate.html) subclass for a skin, you can get a [Title](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classTitle.html) object for the current page using `$this->getSkin()->getTitle()`.

Once you have the Title object, you can call [`getLinkURL()`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classTitle.html#accb458f6fd6090d5ee30f64218721208) on it to get the URL of the page.  (You probably *don't* want to use [`getPrefixedURL()`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classTitle.html#a37f2408046544cb7b67f4e62c3bc3a99) as Ilya suggests, as that just gives you an URL-encoded version of the page name.)  Or you can pass the Title object to [`Linker::link()`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classLinker.html#a52523fb9f10737404b1dfa45bab61045) if you want to generate a standard wikilink-style link without having to mess with URLs yourself.

In fact, `$this-getSkin()` is the general way to gain access to "request-global" MediaWiki objects like the current Title, [WebRequest](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classWebRequest.html), [User](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classUser.html), [Language](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classLanguage.html), [OutputPage](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classOutputPage.html), etc. from a skin template.  Specifically, the [Skin](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classSkin.html) class implements the [IContextSource](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/interfaceIContextSource.html) interface, which provides access to all those objects.

Comment: Hi Ilmari,

Thats brilliant! It works! Since my skin was based on Vector, I got the  title with $this->getSkin()->getTitle(); by using it inside the BaseTemplate and then using the getLinkURL() to get that page's URL.

Thank you so much....

Answer (score 2):

Since your know current page name ($name), you can use MediaWiki Title (see http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Title.php ). As I understand, it must looks like this:

```
$title = Title::newFromText($name);
$url = $title->getPrefixedUrl();
```

Comment: In my case, I dont know the name of the current page. It can be any page that the user is on. So I want to find the page url of whatever page the user was on.